# Any way to display all spotify playlists from a specific user (ios)

Tags: ios, spotify

So, I'm creating an iPhone app for a magazine and they want to be able to share playlists with the users in a similar style to the Urban Outfitters iPhone app. The main difference being the way its displayed and using the companies Spotify account.

I registered the app with Spotify, and I was wondering if there would be a way to complete something like the screenshots shown below.

The goals here being: 
grab all the playlists from 'user'
display them in a table (similar to screen one taking the playlist title and image)
and then on click show the full playlist while staying in the app
(the person using the app won't have access to anything like editing the playlists, this is just for listening the companies pre made playlists)

*they would also like users to be able to listen to the playlists without leaving the app*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are asking two questions:

1. How do I grab a Spotify user's playlists?
2. How do I create a specific UI

#### Spotify Playlist Data

To get a list of playlists for a specific Spotify user, use the API endpoint:

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists
```

This will return JSON formatted data that you can parse to get the data you are interested in. Once you have the list of playlists, you can get playlist specific data by hitting the API endpoint:

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}
```

For more information, check out [Spotify's API documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/)

#### UI

Once you have the data retrieved from these API endpoints you'll be able to populate your tableviews quite easily.

Edit: I just saw your edit about playing music, you should check out the [Spotify SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/) - it looks like it can handle playing tracks.